# Apache and MYSQL not starting in XAMP

Tags: mysql, apache, zend-framework, localhost

I have a problem here that I had my XAMP up and running, I installed ZEND Framework, ZEND Server and ZEND Studio into my system. Now the problem is that localhost is not working. I researched to find out that both can be on a pc and run but I will have to choose between the apache for the two. I stopped the services of Apache Zend but my localhost did not start.

I also checked the error log of apache the last entry is of Today i.e. Tue 10:28am. and XAMP control panel just displays cannot start apache service.

I have changed the apache config file by changing the localhost server port to 8080 instead of 80. But no success yet. MYSQL is also shutting down unexpectedly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Windows 7 Professional, 32 Bit

Comment: Try to check in Services (cmd services.msc) how many apache services you have.

Comment: Uninstalled Zend and XAMP so NONE as of now, reinstalling XAMP..!!

Comment: @GiulioDeMarco runng the services.msc command but apache services are not listed there, Just Installed XAMP and started apache services

Answer (score 2):

I have a same problem when I installed Skype. Skype by default use 80 port number. So you can change it from Skype`s options. For  more info see this link..

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7wj1aaNwbU

Comment: Yes I knew that before hand, I changed the port from 80 to 8080 of Localhost server in my apache config file. Nothing happened. I reinstalled XAMP, changed the settings of Skype to not use PORT no 80 and 443. Signed Out and quit skype NO success. Rebooted No Success. Currently my Apache services are running but MYSQL services are not.!!

Comment: Okay I got it. May be there is some problem in configuration files. Whenever I perfect solution I will tell you.

Comment: Sometimes firewall gives problem on some port numbers. So try with disabled firewall. It is just suggestion. I am not sure.

Comment: I tried almost everything that was on stack, Finally what I did was, uninstalled everything, reinstalled XAMP & ZEND. It is working now. Zend installed MYSQL 5.5 that blocked the port 3306, I changed it's port to 3307 manually in all the .ini files. Debarred skype to use port 80, 443. Your youtube link was useful. Learned some nnice stuff from it.!!

Comment: I am trying to find some perfect solutions. I will tell you about it.

Comment: Give your mail id. I will mail you

Comment: kartikasthana@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this below command in cmd prompt

`netstat -ano|find "port no"`

Eg:

`netstat -ano|find "3306"`

> TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5164
>
> TCP    [::]:3306              [::]:0                 LISTENING       5164

You could even use the pid number and check in windows task manager who is utilizing these pid so that you would come to know the exact process name

Please provide error log file if possible.